# Passing query string to JS window.open in IE7 doesn't work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I can run the following via the address bar in Firefox just fine:

```
javascript:window.open("http://my.hostname.com/test.php?id=12345", "exportWindow");
```

When I print_r($_GET), I see the $_GET array with the values I specified in the URL. But when I do so in IE7, it just prints "null" on screen.

*EDIT*

Turns out that was due to a popup blocker. However, the actual code that uses that snipped doesn't work--I get Array() in IE when print_r-ing:

```
  $Page->addJQuery('$("#pageForm div.export").click(function() { ' . $jQueryVars . 'window.open("' . $this->getUrl() . '"' . $jQueryParams . ', "exportWindow"); return false; });');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to use jQuery's .live rather than .click.

Answer (score 1):

IE is blocking the popup. The 'null' you see is the return value of the JavaScript call. Turn off the popup blocker and it should work.

Comment: Okay, that works. The actual code that uses the snippet doesn't, though. Do you have any ideas on that? When I click the "button," I just get Array() when print_r-ing $_GET. Here is is:       $Page->addJQuery('$("#pageForm div.export").click(function() { ' . $jQueryVars . 'window.open("' . $this->getUrl() . '"' . $jQueryParams . ', "exportWindow"); return false; });');

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for SOME REASON I needed to use .live("click", function() rather than .click(function(). No idea why, as I use .change in several other places which works in IE...but it fixed the problem, nevertheless.